# How to convert nested for loops into a recursive function?

Tags: c, recursion, for-loop

```
for(a[9]=0;a[9]<16;a[9]++)

for(a[8]=0;a[8]<16;a[8]++)

for(a[7]=0;a[7]<16;a[7]++)

for(a[6]=0;a[6]<16;a[6]++)

for(a[5]=0;a[5]<16;a[5]++)

for(a[4]=0;a[4]<16;a[4]++)

for(a[3]=0;a[3]<16;a[3]++)

for(a[2]=0;a[2]<16;a[2]++)

for(a[1]=0;a[1]<16;a[1]++)

for(a[0]=0;a[0]<16;a[0]++)

i++;
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with such a deeply nested loops???

Answer (score 2):

Below logic will helps you for converting a nested for loop to a recursive function. But don't add so much nested `for` loop in code unnecessarily. Performance needs to be consider even while writing small programs.

```
int i = 0; //make it as global variable
...
void func(int a[], int index)
{
   for (a[index] = 0; a[index] < 16; a[index]++)
   {
       if (index != 0)
       {
           func(a, (index - 1));
       }
       else
       {
           i++;
       }
   }
}
```